# Can I use a Walmart iPhone 5c charger instead of the original one

Tags: iphone

I got a new charger at Walmart and it does not charge the phone. Is it because it is cheap?

Comment: Please provide link to which charger? usually they are just 5 Volt USB output with Cable that fits iPhone on the other end. The cable might be defective so return/exchange it. There is no rocket science about that product. Means, yes you can use it.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/66449/38539

Answer (score 2):

When buying an iPhone charger what you want to look for is the lightning cable (the one for your 5C) having a MFI-Certification, this means that it is certified by Apple to work (most likely). These may be more expensive but are better than the .99 gas station chargers. It may still work for a while buy there is a fairly high chance it won't or it will die after just a few weeks. Your best bet is a more expensive one from a place like Amazon or one sold at an actual Apple store.

To answer your question, cheap chargers are not nearly as good and could not end up working.

Comment: Yeah, pay the extra and get a good brand, like Belkin, or just get the official Apple one for $20.

Answer (score 0):

basicly my family is a bit frugal and we tried all of the chargers; third party ones and the super cheap "certified" ones.  My advice is to get the apple one or a very nice one like [http://www.amazon.com/MOS-Spring-Lightning-Cable-Exoskeleton/dp/B00XZ8DYM0/ref=sr_1_15?s=wireless&ie=UTF8&qid=1438736350&sr=1-15-spons&keywords=lightning%20cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XZ8DYM0)

Answer (score 0):

No - cheap doesn't cause problems. Expensive also can fail, it's probably just a failure you can address by returning the adapter to the seller.